# Is using FormBuilder in the constructor a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic4

[Angular doc here](https://angular.io/start/forms) you can see below kind of implementation.i.e declare `formBuilder` and services inside the `constructor()`. I know use services inside the `constructor()` is a bad practice. i.e. we need to use `ngOnInit()` for that. But I also use `constructor()` for declaring `formBuilder` properties. Is that too bad practice? Do I need to use `ngOnInit()` for that too? Will page creation holds until `formBuilder` creation?

```
export class CartComponent {
  items;
  checkoutForm;

  constructor(
    private cartService: CartService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.items = this.cartService.getItems();

    this.checkoutForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      name: '',
      address: ''
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `ngOnInit()` would be the most appropriate place for that too. *Will page creation holds until formBuilder creation?* -- Yes, but in your case that *wait* is negligible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer, yes, you should leave most of the initialisation logic within the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook.

According to the angular docs for [OnInit](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit), it is used to

> - To perform complex initializations shortly after construction.
> - To set up the component after Angular sets the input properties.

Therefore, it will be cleaner to carry out logic such as fetching of data, and initialisation of your formbuilders on your `ngOnInit` lifeycle hook.

You should check out this [post](http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/) by Misko Hevery, who is the team lead for Angular, who has outlined a number of reasons to keep the constructor clean.

Answer (score 1):

#### Injecting `FormBuilder` in the Constructor

Injecting `FormBuilder` in the `constructor` is the recommended best practice, since Angular uses the *constructor injection pattern*.

#### Using `FormBuilder` in the Constructor

Whether or not to initialize the reactive form in the `constructor` or the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook is largely a matter of preference. But in the interest of keeping code tidy, refactoring initialization logic into `ngOnInit` (or other methods) is a good idea.

Regarding the timing of `ngOnInit`, the docs state:

> [`ngOnInit` is a] callback method that is invoked immediately after the default change detector has checked the directive's data-bound properties for the first time, and ***before any of the view or content children have been checked***. It is invoked only once when the directive is instantiated.

Hence, initializing a form in `ngOnInit` will take place prior to the page view being loaded.

---

The official Angular docs for [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) initialize the form as follows:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile-editor',
  templateUrl: './profile-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile-editor.component.css']
})
export class ProfileEditorComponent {
  profileForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: [''],
    address: this.fb.group({
      street: [''],
      city: [''],
      state: [''],
      zip: ['']
    }),
    aliases: this.fb.array([
      this.fb.control('')
    ])
  });

  get aliases() {
    return this.profileForm.get('aliases') as FormArray;
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

See [<kbd>**Angular Stackblitz Demo**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/angular/galbpkbnady)